# make a button similar to the span in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button like below with me.

```
<button type="submit" class="search-btn" id="search-submit-header"></button>
```

It has certain functionality which I want to apply to this span so that It does the same work as the button. I want to use the CSS of the span.

```
<span class="search-btn">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
</span>
```

How can I get this. i.e. Functionality of the button working on the span.

Apologies for a dumb question.

Comment: please post your work till now

Comment: I am unable to figure out. don't think I am close so can't post something..

Comment: I can't get your point. Basically, you can add `btn` class to the span, and it will be a btn in terms of design. And you should swap `<a>` with  `<span>`, it's more semantic this way.

Comment: For this to work you will have to replicate the `button` click js and css to `span`. Just inspect the selector to find if `button` is used or its just using the class `.search-btn`. If `button` then it will have to be replicated to `span`. Not sure with what's the purpose of this requirement though.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put the style info to anchor tag. For Example check below line

```
<a href="#" class="search-btn">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</a>
```

**Note:** Clear all the style information of anchor tag 
and write supporting javascript code

```
   function doSomething(){
     //your code
    }
   $('.search-btn').click(doSomething);
```

Comment: Why on earth put it in an <a> tag?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <style>
        .ButtonSpan {
            /*width: 500px;
            height: 500px;*/
            border: 1px solid black;
            background: #e0e0e0;
            padding: 25px;
        }
    </style>
    <button type="submit" class="ButtonSpan">test</button>
    <span class="ButtonSpan">test</span>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Find what `css` is currently applied on your `<button>` element.

   There are several ways to do it but the most simple one is (in chrome) you can right-click > inspect element > press "ctrl + shift + c" and click on button > elements tab > Computed tab (on RHS) and see what `css` is currently applied.
2. Copy major properties of css from there and apply them on `span.search-btn` class in css.

   for example:

   ```
   span.search-btn {
       width: 20px;
       height: 10px;
       border: 1px solid black;
       padding: 20px;
   }
   ```